# How to restart windows VM from another Machine

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine

I have a Windows Virtual machine and this is currently in hang mode. When I log into my VM, It successfully logs in but VM is in hanged mode so I cannot do anything. It shows only a blank blue screen. I cannot open *Run* command so that I may restart my VM. The problem is that I can not manually restart my VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your VM and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. You will get the *Windows Security* window. Now you can restart your VM using the *Shutdown* option.

Comment: Or just force the VM to power off.

Answer (score 0):

Solution A - GUI + keyboard
If your a keyboard shortcut fan, you may have already known that Alt+F4 closes the currently selected Windows application. When your desktop is selected, it stands to reason that typing Alt+F4 has the effect of telling Windows that you'd like to close Windows itself. Simple, elegant, and easy to remember!

Press Win+D to minimized all open Windows to show your desktop
(alternatively, you can left-click the lower-right corner)
Press Alt+F4 to bring up the Shut Down Windows - What do you want the computer to do? dialog, where you can now choose any of the following list of actions:
Disconnect
Sign out
Shut down
Restart
Select which option you want, then press Enter (or click OK)